# Let $X$ have pdf $f(x) = e^{-x}$. Find the pdf of the integer part of $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A continuous random variable has a pdf defined by
>   $$f(x) = e^{-x} , x > 0.$$ 
>   The discrete random variable $Y$ is defined as the integer part of $X$, that is the largest integer less than or equal to $X$. Find the pdf of $Y$.

The connection between the two RV $X$ and $Y$ is my problem , how do I start the derivation of .

Comment: Also, $Y$ is a discrete random variable, so you should be looking for the **pmf** rather than the *pdf*.

Comment: Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In other words, $Y = \lfloor X\rfloor$. Recall that $$\lfloor X \rfloor = k\iff k\leq X<k+1.$$

Hence
$$\{Y = k\}\iff\{\lfloor X \rfloor = k\}\iff \{k\leq X<k+1\}.$$